# Use base adapter with asynctask to display listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

i am reading data from soap service and want to display them in a list.
to do this, I have created a base adapter. And trying to use that in asynctask. But that is giving some error that i dont have a solution. as per the error i think there is some problem in the postExecute in the asynctask, but don't have idea how to solve it.
some help will be really great.

here is some of the codes.

### the class

```
public class PatientBasicInfo {
private String FirstName;
private String LastName;
private String Id;
private String Gender;
private String DateOfBirth;

public PatientBasicInfo(String firstname,String lastname,String id){
    this.FirstName=firstname;
    this.LastName=lastname;
    this.Id=id;
}

public String getFirstName(){
    return this.FirstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstname){
    this.FirstName=firstname;
}

public String getLastName(){
    return this.LastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastname){
    this.LastName=lastname;
}
public String getPatientId(){
    return this.Id;
}
public void setPatientId(String Id){
    this.Id=Id;
}
public String getGender(){
    return this.Gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender){
    this.Gender=gender;
}
public String getDateOfBirth(){
    return this.DateOfBirth;
}
public void setDateOfBirth(String dob){
    this.DateOfBirth=dob;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return FirstName+" "+LastName;
}

}
```

### The base adapter

```
public class PatientListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private static ArrayList<PatientBasicInfo> patientArrayList;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;

public PatientListBaseAdapter(Context ctx,ArrayList<PatientBasicInfo> result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    patientArrayList=result;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context=ctx;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return patientArrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return patientArrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    final String patientId=patientArrayList.get(position).getPatientId();
    final String patientFirstName=patientArrayList.get(position).getFirstName();
    final String patientLastName=patientArrayList.get(position).getLastName();
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_rowview, null);
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.txtFirstName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.patientfirstname);
           holder.txtLastName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.patientlastname);
           holder.txtID=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.patientid);

           convertView.setTag(holder);
          } else {
              holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
          }

    holder.txtFirstName.setText(patientFirstName);
    holder.txtLastName.setText(patientLastName);

    holder.txtID.setText(patientId);
    return convertView;
}
private class ViewHolder {
      TextView txtFirstName;      
      TextView txtID;
      TextView txtLastName; 

     }}
```

### the activity

```
public class PatientListActivity extends Activity{

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getPatientList";
private static final String URL = "";


TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_listview);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String nurseId  = intent.getStringExtra("nurseid");

    new CallgetPatientList().execute(nurseId);
}

class CallgetPatientList extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ArrayList<PatientBasicInfo>>{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<PatientBasicInfo> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("param", params[0].toString());
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

        Credetials cred=new Credetials("username","password");
        PropertyInfo credPropertyinfo=new PropertyInfo();
        credPropertyinfo.setName("credetials");
        credPropertyinfo.setValue(cred);
        credPropertyinfo.setType(cred.getClass());

        request.addProperty(credPropertyinfo);
        request.addProperty("nurseId", params[0].toString());

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

     try{

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);


            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

            ArrayList<PatientBasicInfo> patientList=new ArrayList<PatientBasicInfo>();

            for(int i= 0; i< response.getPropertyCount(); i++){
                SoapObject object = (SoapObject)response.getProperty(i);
                String firstname=object.getProperty("firstName").toString();
                String lastname=object.getProperty("lastName").toString();

                String id=object.getProperty("id").toString();

               PatientBasicInfo aa=new PatientBasicInfo(firstname,lastname,id);                
               patientList.add(aa);
            }

            Log.d("patientCount", Integer.toString(patientList.size()));
            return patientList;


        }catch(Exception e){
            //return e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<PatientBasicInfo> result){
        //super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d("resultcount", Integer.toString(result.size()));
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        PatientListBaseAdapter adapter=new PatientListBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(),result);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_patient_list, menu);
    //return true;


    return true;

}
}
```

### the error

[image]

Comment: where is line number 27 in PatientListBaseAdapter ?

Comment: didn't get you? do you mean mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); this is line number 27.

Comment: dude...thanks...the error was in line 27. great. if you write that in answer, i will mark it. cheers

Comment: most welcome friend .you can also upvote answer if u think it really help u in solving issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are passing NULL context to `LayoutInflater.from` so use change  `PatientListBaseAdapter` constructor code as :

```
public PatientListBaseAdapter(Context ctx,ArrayList<PatientBasicInfo> result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    patientArrayList=result;
    this.context=ctx;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);

}
```